# IntegrityError when creating relationships to imported records

Tags: django

I'm running into IntegrityError when creating a relation to an object that is in the db from importing via mysql xx < whatever.sql

Its a relationship to the standard auth.contrib.models.User, using 1.3.1

If I clear the DB and create a new user manually, I can create my related object without issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `whatever.sql` includes that user record?

Comment: @AdamKG, yip, in the shell i have created a new related item with no references to User, then got a user via foo = User.objects.get(id = 1) then tried related_object.related_field.add(foo) ... same thing

Comment: just spotted the tables i have imported are MyISAM and the new ones i've created locally via south are InnoDB, will look up if that can cause a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a mix between InnoDB (new tables created by south) and MyISAM (old tables from the import),

Foreign keys cant exist between these.

Developing on a windows machine, all defaults in the mysql config had the default table type as InnoDB, import was from a linux server where default was MyISAM.